# Що означає слово "гоцати"?

Tags: значення-слів

Натрапила на статтю ["Після народження третьої дитини дізналася, що хвора на рак"](http://visnyk.lutsk.ua/news/ukraine/regions/rivne/21339/), однак у ній помітила незрозуміле слово "***гоцати***" у такому контексті:

> – Діана хоче постійно на руки. От бачте, не злазить з Таниних колін, – крізь сльози каже старенька. – Коли я сама, то все більше у ліжечко її ставлю. Не маю вже таких сил з нею ***гоцати***.

Як завжди, звертаюсь у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghocaty), однак його там не знаходжу. То що ж означає це слово? Як зрозуміти правильно це речення?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаходимо у [Словарі українського сленгу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53395/374168.html):

> **ГОЦАТИ** 
>   (-аю, -аєш) недок. 
>   1. крим. Танцювати. БСРЖ, 137; ЯБМ, 1, 243. 
>   2. муз. Бити в барабан. ПСУМС, 18.

Також у [Лексиконі львівському](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53395/1061664.html):

> **гоцати** 
>   го́цати (гу́цати) вул. танцювати (м, ср, ст): Бу на Личакові треба фест фраєра, Аби з батярами гуцати штаєра (із пісні)|| = гасати

Отже, **гоцати – танцювати**. Це слово часто вживається на позначення не танцю як такого, а як забави для дітей, коли дитина сідає на коліна дорослої людини, а та її «підкидає».